# Why getOrElse would lose type inference in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

When I use Either type in Scalaz, it is a very good design, but method getOrElse would lose type inference.

```
val either = ~3.right[String] | "123" // either: String

val either = 3.right[String] | "123" // either: Any
```

why val either = 3.right[String] | "123" not refer Int, but Any occurred.

Is it a flaw or it is part of design ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`3.right[String]` is of type `\/-[String, Int]`
i.e. you have an `Int` on the right and a `String` on the left. However you're also providing a `String` as fallback value for the right side.

The compiler looks then for the lowest common supertype of `String` and `Int`, which happens to be `Any`.

Remember that the type parameter will give information about the "missing" side: if you have a `right` it will mark the type of the `left`, and vice versa.

In the first case you're saying: I have a left `Int`, my right will be a `String` (which is consistent with "123" passed as right fallback value)

In the latter you're saying: I have a right `Int`, my left will be a `String`, but you're then providing a `String` as a right.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is the type constraint that `BB >: B` in the definition of `|` and `\/`. See https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L202-L210

```
sealed abstract class \/[+A, +B] {
...
  def getOrElse[BB >: B](x: => BB): BB = ...

  def |[BB >: B](x: => BB): BB = ...
...
}
```

`BB >: B` means that `BB` must be a super type of `B`. In your example, `B` is `Int` and `"123"` is `String`. As @Gabriele Petronella pointed out, `BB` is inferred to be the "lowest common supertype" of `Int` and `String`, which happens to be `Any`.

If the signature were the following instead, your example would fail to compile.

```
sealed abstract class \/[+A, +B] {
...
  def getOrElse[B](x: => B): B = ...

  def |[B](x: => B): B = ...
...
}
```

Given the definitions above, `x: B`, which in your example is `Int`. "123" is not `Int`.